# Jsoup: escape behaviour of 1.8.1 like in 1.7.2

Tags: escaping, jsoup

I want to update Jsoup from version 1.7.2 to 1.8.1. 
As announced in the changelog, the escaping behaviour has changed.
In my application I want the output html to be escaped, no matter what charset is defined.

Having the following code:

```
String test = "äöüèéàÄÖÜÀÉÈ\"&°";
Document document = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(test);
System.out.println(document.body().html());
```

1.7.2 output:

> &auml;&ouml;&uuml;&egrave;&eacute;&agrave;&Auml;&Ouml;&Uuml;&Agrave;&Eacute;&Egrave;&quot;&amp;&deg;

1.8.1 output:

> äöüèéàÄÖÜÀÉÈ\"&°

What would be the best way to get back the 1.7.2 behaviour?
I tried setting the charset to ASCII:

```
document.outputSettings().charset(Charset.forName("ASCII"));
```

But then quotes are not escaped, and maybe other characters...

Comment: Can I ask why you want to escape characters you don't need to? Setting ascii is right if you will be outputting ascii, and it will escape most characters. But " only needs to be escaped in attributes. This contributes to smaller HTML filers and faster processing. (Happy to modify this behavior if I understand the root-cause/need.) I got a lot of feedback against the previous behavior of optimistic escaping, which prompted the change.

Comment: I'm using Jsoup to escape HTML, storing the result in a database. 
Where and how it is consumed/ouputed is not sure, mostly it will be UTF-8, but could be other encodings as well.
An additional EscapeMode which provides previous behaviour would be great!

Comment: OK, but how does storing it in a DB change it -- if you don't know what you will set the output charset to be, set it to ascii (like you are). It will render correctly. Quotes only need to be escaped in attributes, and they will be.

Comment: good point! Are there other characters that are not beeing escaped or are quotes the only one for sure?

Comment: The only characters that need to be escaped are: ones that the charset can't encode; or ones that are used for HTML markup, which differs if in an attribute or out. Here's the code: https://github.com/jhy/jsoup/blob/80158d6fa7445506eaaafdeadb1f4dc291ca10a5/src/main/java/org/jsoup/nodes/Entities.java#L111